# Nginx Is Showing the Default Page Instead of the Django Application

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I am hosting a django website on gunicorn/nginx with ubuntu 22.04. I am following below guide for configuration.
it is still showing the default nginx site. (I know there are similar question and also the troubleshooting guide and potential reasons also given in the document i am following; I tried everything but could not solve the issue.

Infrastructure :

1. ubuntu 22.04
2. Hestial CP - Using for firewall instead using ufw (bcoz with Hestia default ufw is not installed)
3. Postgres
4. Django
5. gunicorn/nginx

Followed all the steps and performed the verification at each stage the document suggest and its showing positive results. but when i am trying to access my site it is still showing the default nginx site.

Configuration:

1. etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com; 
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/myuser/main/myproject;
        }
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass //unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
    }
```

2. etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
    [Unit]
    Description=gunicorn daemon
    Requires=gunicorn.socket
    After=network.target
    
    [Service]
    User=myuser
    Group=www-data
    WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/main/myproject
    ExecStart=/home/myuser/main/envProject/bin/gunicorn \
              --access-logfile - \
              --workers 3 \
              --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
              myproject.wsgi:application
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. gunicorn.socket

```
    [Unit]
    Description=gunicorn socket
    
    [Socket]
    ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=sockets.target
```

4. Firewall (I have opened all major ports without ip restrictions, shall start closing once the setup works)
   [image]

PS: The strangest part is after activating virtual env and run manually command "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi" i am able to access myexample.com:8000

access log

```
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:02:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:02:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:08:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:08:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:08:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:13:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:33:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:33:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:35:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:35:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:36:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
141.98.11.207 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:43:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46" "-"
162.216.150.180 - - [01/Jul/2023:06:57:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Expanse, a Palo Alto Networks company, searches across the global IPv4 space multiple times per day to identify customers&#39; presences on the Internet. If you would like to be excluded from our scans, please send IP addresses/domains to: scaninfo@paloaltonetworks.com" "-"
43.206.208.110 - - [01/Jul/2023:07:05:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/112.0.5615.29 Safari/537.36" "-"
83.97.73.89 - - [01/Jul/2023:07:05:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
117.235.235.145 - - [01/Jul/2023:07:08:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.201.180.210 - - [01/Jul/2023:07:22:19 +0000] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:07:29:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
103.241.224.248 - - [01/Jul/2023:07:29:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
91.224.92.16 - - [01/Jul/2023:07:36:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "-" "-"
```

nginx error log:

```
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 21624#21624: signal 15 (SIGTERM) received from 27750, exiting
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 21625#21625: exiting
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 21625#21625: exit
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 21624#21624: signal 15 (SIGTERM) received from 1, exiting
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 21624#21624: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 21625
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 21624#21624: worker process 21625 exited with code 0
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 21624#21624: exit
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 27751#27751: using the "epoll" event method
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 27751#27751: nginx/1.25.1
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 27751#27751: built by gcc 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 27751#27751: OS: Linux 5.15.0-76-generic
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 27751#27751: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:524288
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 27755#27755: start worker processes
2023/07/01 06:35:24 [notice] 27755#27755: start worker process 27756
2023/07/01 07:22:19 [error] 27756#27756: *9 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-login.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 173.201.180.210, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", host: "arhamerp.com"
2023/07/01 07:36:42 [notice] 27755#27755: signal 15 (SIGTERM) received from 40856, exiting
2023/07/01 07:36:42 [notice] 27756#27756: signal 15 (SIGTERM) received from 1, exiting
2023/07/01 07:36:42 [notice] 27756#27756: exiting
2023/07/01 07:36:42 [notice] 27755#27755: signal 15 (SIGTERM) received from 1, exiting
2023/07/01 07:36:42 [notice] 27756#27756: exit
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 27755#27755: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 27756
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 27755#27755: worker process 27756 exited with code 0
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 27755#27755: exit
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 40857#40857: using the "epoll" event method
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 40857#40857: nginx/1.25.1
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 40857#40857: built by gcc 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 40857#40857: OS: Linux 5.15.0-76-generic
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 40857#40857: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:524288
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 40859#40859: start worker processes
2023/07/01 07:36:43 [notice] 40859#40859: start worker process 40860
```

[image]
Please help me understand the issue and the solution.

Thanks,
A

Comment: Can you share nginx access and error logs, and the default page which is showing on browser

Comment: @vinay vishwakarma: i have updated the error log and access log in the question

Comment: Why do your access logs list php endpoints? And please don't open random ports like SSH to the open internet to test an HTTP server

Comment: @OneCricketeer: i think the php logs are from the HestiaCP, used to open the firewall ports. i will install the ssl later and move to https. i hope thats not the prob for the default page.

Comment: @AhmedRaza, your logs are quite confusing, does not help to identify the issue. Please share the logs related to your Django site only. Also share the browser page screen shot which  you are trying to access.

Comment: @VinayVishwakarma: updated access log and error log and the screen shot

Comment: Your proxy_pass syntax is incorrect for sockets - https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass but you can also use http://localhost:8000 You'll also want to verify nginx main config file is reading your sites-available folder

Comment: @OneCricketeer: I tried changing the proxy_pass settings by adding http before the current path, also tried with localhost:8000.  Can you please explain how to verify nginx main config file is reading sites-available folder

Comment: Are you still looking into this? If it's successfully running on port 8000 you should be able to just use `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;`.